# How do you organize unit tests into packages?

Tags: unit-testing, packaging

As a matter of fact you have smth like `/java/src` and `/java/test`. But then, how do you name packages/classes the unittests go to? The same as classes they are written against? And when refactoring comes, do you manually rename in /test? Please share your experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I keep the tests in the same package as the class they are testing.  This allows me to setup tests using package private members (when required).  It also provides a nice, easy to remember convention.  When I refactor, I usually do manually refactor the corresponding test classes.  There was some IDE a while back that had the ability to do this refactoring automatically, but I can't remember it off the top of my head.

Comment: When you do a build, do you have to remove or somehow exclude the tests?

Answer (score 1):

In Java, keeping them in the same package as the class being tested, is a must. It's the only way to test methods with default/package-protected visibility.